# Temporary name resolution error with Test Kitchen EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, test-kitchen

When I run kitchen create with the config below I get an error:

```
"[getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution] on default-centos-7".
```

This system can resolve dns no issues so I'm not sure what the issue is...

```
---
driver:
  name: ec2
  aws_ssh_key_id: chef
  security_group_ids: ["sg-5d3276a0"]
  region: eu-east-1
  require_chef_omnibus: true
  instance_type: t1.micro
  associate_public_ip: true

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  cookbook_path: cookbooks
  roles_path: roles
  environments_path: environments
  data_bags_path: data_bags

platforms:
  - name: centos-7
    image_id: ami-96a818fe
    transport:
      ssh_key: /home/user/aws_key.pem
      username: root

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[website::default]
    attributes:
```

Changing the Platform to an ubuntu ami gives the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `eu-east-1` region. Perhaps you meant `eu-west-1`?